# Installing OCaml Core on Fedora 20

Tags: linux, fedora

I just got the Real World OCaml book and they are using the Jane Street Core standard library in the book. This means that without it, most of the code in the book does not compile. It seems like Core is not available as a package in Fedora 20. Does anyone recommend a good way to install this. I've tried to install OPAM on Fedora, which contains it, but I'm unable to get it to compile.

Here's some output:

```
$ opam install core
...
===== ERROR while installing type_conv.109.53.02 =====
# opam-version 1.1.0
# os           linux
# command      make
# path         /home/user/.opam/system/build/type_conv.109.53.02
# compiler     system (4.00.1)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /home/user/.opam/system/build/type_conv.109.53.02/type_conv-1610-1872ec.env
# stdout-file  /home/user/.opam/system/build/type_conv.109.53.02/type_conv-1610-1872ec.out
# stderr-file  /home/user/.opam/system/build/type_conv.109.53.02/type_conv-1610-1872ec.err
### stdout ###
# ocamlopt.opt -o setup.exe setup.ml || ocamlopt -o setup.exe setup.ml || ocamlc -o setup.exe setup.ml
# rm -f setup.cmx setup.cmi setup.o setup.obj setup.cmo
# ./setup.exe -configure 
### stderr ###
# ocamlfind: Package `camlp4.quotations' not found
# W: Field 'pkg_camlp4_quotations' is not set: Command ''/home/user/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind' query -format %d camlp4.quotations > '/tmp/oasis-715a9f.txt'' terminated with error code 2
# ocamlfind: Package `camlp4.extend' not found
# W: Field 'pkg_camlp4_extend' is not set: Command ''/home/user/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind' query -format %d camlp4.extend > '/tmp/oasis-968a42.txt'' terminated with error code 2
# E: Cannot find findlib package camlp4.extend
# E: Cannot find findlib package camlp4.quotations
# E: Failure("2 configuration errors")
# make: *** [setup.data] Error 1
```

This is the set of OCaml packages that I have installed on my system:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep ocaml | sort
ocaml-4.00.1-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-camlp4-4.00.1-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-camlp4-devel-4.00.1-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-camlp5-6.07-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-camlp5-devel-6.07-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-compiler-libs-4.00.1-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-ocamldoc-4.00.1-3.fc20.x86_64
ocaml-runtime-4.00.1-3.fc20.x86_64
```

Comment: People who develop opam and RWO authors as well frequent the (main) [OCaml mailing list](http://ocaml.org/community/mailing_lists.html). It might be easier/faster to get help there.